# Gambas3 setting Cursor position

Tags: gambas

I am using a qt5 TextEdit in Gambas3 for rich text.

Please consider the code:

```
    Dim cursorpos As Integer

  If Key.Code = Key.Left Or Key.Code = Key.Up Or Key.code = Key.Right Or Key.Code = Key.Down Or Key.Code = Key.Delete Or Key.Code = Key.Backspace Then
    
    cursorpos = TextEdit1.Pos ' just pick the position
    Print cursorpos
    
  Else 
    cursorpos = TextEdit1.Pos
    Print cursorpos
    TextEdit1.RichText = "<font color = \"#224444\">" & Replace(TextEdit1.Text, gb.NewLine, "<br>") & "</font>" ' this preserves the newlines, and replaces them with a <br> for the rich text
    Print "setting : ", cursorpos ' prints the correct value
    TextEdit1.Pos = cursorpos ' does not work
    Print "got : ", TextEdit1.Pos ' jumps to the end of the string
  Endif
```

Now, I write :

```
This si a line
this is a second line
```

I have a typo on the first line. I use my arrow key to get there. I hit backspace twice, and remove the word `si`. All good. Now I expect to type in the character i, and the cursor should stay just after the character i. But as soon as the i is typed in the correct position, the cursor jumps to the end of the text.

Please help. How can I keep the cursor position in the correct place? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your error is this line...

```
TextEdit1.RichText = "<font color = \"#224444\">" & Replace(TextEdit1.Text, gb.NewLine, "<br>") & "</font>" 
' this preserves the newlines, and replaces them with a <br> for the rich text
```

actually it removes the hidden original RichText formatting

The best way to change color of the text inline without changing the internal RichText formatting is to do something like this...

```
TextEdit1.Format.Color = Color.Red
```

then text typed at that position will be in red.

So you could monitor for Delete / Backspace then set the format color to red at the current position.

[gambaswiki.org/wiki/comp/gb.qt4.ext/textedit](http://gambaswiki.org/wiki/comp/gb.qt4.ext/textedit)